# How to have multiple success callbacks for 1 promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a function `loadItems()` that loads something async, and then fails or succeeds. Both fail and success callbacks must do something in the library, and then pass it on to the implementer, which can choose to implement fail, or success, or both, or none.

The problem I now have is if the library implements both the success and fail handler, it will always return a new promise that resolves to success.

This is what I have:

```
// The library:
function loadItems() {
    return store.get('todo').then(function(rsp) {
        // Save these locally
        items = rsp.value || [];
    }, function(rsp) {
        // Do nothing, but let the user know
        alert(rsp.error);
    });
}
```

`store.get('todo')` (from yet another library) returns a promise. `loadItems()` has no control over it.

```
// The library implementer:
function init() {
    loadItems().then(showItems);
}
```

What I want, and expected to happen:

1. `loadItems()` runs the async code from the library (`store.get()`)
2. It implements `success` and `fail` because they have mandatory actions
3. It passes the success/failure on to the implementer
4. The implementer only implements `success`, because it doesn't care about errors, because the library handled it
5. So it uses `.then(onSuccess)` to 'add another success callback'

What happens instead (with an error):

1. The library's failure callback is executed
2. A new promise is passed on to the implementer
3. The new promise always resolves with success
4. The implementer's success callback is fired, with broken result, because the library's success callback didn't fire

Are Promises seriously too cool to have multiple, **sync** success handlers??

I can imagine even the source library (that defines `store.get()`) wants to handle the error (for logging sneakily), and then pass success/failure on.

My 'solutions':

1. Have `loadItems()`' failure callback throw an error. Unfortunately, that means `init()` has to catch it (or the browser whines about it). Not cool.
2. Use a simple callback to talk back to `init()`, instead of a promise, which only fires after a success. That's not good, because `init()` **might** choose to handle the error some day.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but I don't see it.

Comment: Please read this: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: What promise implementation are you using?

Comment: "*Unfortunately, that means init() has to catch it (or the browser whines about it). Not cool.*" - not sure what you mean. A promise rejection is like an exception in that regard, and it seems to be exactly what you want?

Comment: @CarlosCarucce I'm not using jQuery.

Comment: @Bergi I'm using native Promises in Chrome. I don't want every 'implementer' to handle the error, because the error is already handled by `loadItems()`. `init()` only cares about the result IF it worked. If not, doesn't matter, but don't execute `then()` as if it did work.

Comment: the code at `// Do nothing, but let the user know` is run on failure, and has no return value, i.e. equivalent to `return undefined` - so that `then` will return a fulfilled promise with value = undfined ... read how promises work for a better explanation

Comment: @Deux: If you don't want the callers to handle the error, you must not reject the promise you return to them (like you're already doing). If you want them to be able to handle the error but they don't, it'll get logged as an unhandled rejection. There's no way out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a reject handler to do something based on the error, but want the returned promise to still be rejected, you just rethrow the error (or return a rejected promise) after your reject handling code.  This will allow the reject to propagate back through the returned promise.

```
// The library:
function loadItems() {
    return store.get('todo').then(function(rsp) {
        // Save these locally
        items = rsp.value || [];
    }, function(rsp) {
        // Do nothing, but let the user know
        alert(rsp.error);
        // rethrow the error so the returned promise will still be rejected
        throw(rsp);
    });
}
```

Supplying a reject handler that does not throw or return a rejected promise tells the promise system that you have "handled" the error and the return value of your reject handler becomes the new fulfilled value of the promise.  So, if you want the promise to "stay" rejected, but want to have a handler to do something based on the rejection (logging the rejection is very common), then you have to either rethrow the error in your reject handler or return a rejected promise.

While this may initially seem counter-intuitive, it gives you the most flexibility because you can either completely handle the error and let the returned promise be resolved "successfully" OR you can choose to tell the promise system that you want to propagate an error and you can even choose which error you want that to be (it does not have to be the same error).

---

The part of your question about multiple success handlers is a bit confusing to me.  You can easily have multiple success handlers with any promise:

```
var p = someFuncThatReturnsSuccessfulPromise();
p.then(someSuccessHandler);
p.then(someOtherSuccessHandler);
```

If `p` is a successfully resolved promise, then these two success handlers will both be called in the order they are attached and what happens in `someSuccessHandler` will have no impact on whether `someOtherSuccessHandler` is called or not. If the original promise is resolved successfully, then both handlers will always be called.

If you chain your success handlers, then it is a completely different use case.  This is completely different:

```
var p = someFuncThatReturnsSuccessfulPromise();
p.then(someSuccessHandler).then(someOtherSuccessHandler);
```

Because the second `.then()` handler is not attached to `p`, but is attached to `p.then(someSuccessHandler)` which is a different promise whose outcome is potentially influenced by what happens in `someSuccessHandler`.

The code in your question is chained.  You are returning:

```
 return store.get().then(...)
```

So, when the caller then chains onto that, the full chain is:

```
 return store.get().then(yourhandler).then(theirhandler)
```

In this way, `yourhandler` can influence the outcome that is passed to `theirhandler`.

---

In addition to my first recommendation of just rethrowing the error, you could also have done this:

```
// The library:
function loadItems() {
    var p = store.get('todo');
    p.then(function(rsp) {
        // Save these locally
        items = rsp.value || [];
    }, function(rsp) {
        // Do nothing, but let the user know
        alert(rsp.error);
    });
    return p;
}
```

Here you ware making sure that your handlers don't affect what is being returned.  This can be done if you don't have any async operations in your handlers and you aren't trying to change the resolved value or rejected error of the original `store.get()` promise.  I generally don't recommend this because it is a cause for problems if your handlers are doing other async things or want to influence the return values, but it can also be used in appropriate circumstances.

Comment: @Deux - Did this answer your question?

Comment: I tried the last thing (returning the original Promise), but I still get the 'uncaught error in promise' warning from Chrome. I think it's what I mean to do, but it doesn't work as advertised. If I return the original Promise, AND return `Promise.reject()` in the catch, Chrome even throws 2 of those warnings.

Comment: @Deux - What does the code look like that calls `loadItems()`?  If that does not have a reject handler, then this is a valid warning as you have a reject path that is not handled and that's what the warning is trying to tell you.  I also changed the last code block as there is no reason to rethrow the exception there because it will not change the outcome (that might remove the warning).

Comment: It does have a reject handler. That's the whole point: only needing 1 reject handler. But Chrome really wants every handler layer to have a reject handler. I just added an empty, like Promise wants =(